# ERROR 1136 al querer encriptar datos en MYSQL

Tags: mysql

quiero encriptar unos datos en MySql, pero me pone: `ERROR 1136 (21S01): Column count doesn't match value count at row 1`

mi tabla es:
`mysql> create table login(idu varchar(25), user varbinary(150), pass varbinary(150));`

y al querer hacer un registro con los datos encriptado me sale el error ya mencionado

`mysql> insert into login (idu,user,pass) values ('2', AES_ENCRYPT('test02','12345'));`

`ERROR 1136 (21S01): Column count doesn't match value count at row 1`

tengo algún error de sintaxis? o algún dato que este metiendo mal, de ante mano muchas gracias:)

Comment: estas pasando dos datos.. y tu query espera 3... o estan mal los parentesis?

Comment: Según yo estoy pasando 3 datos, el de idu=2, user=test02 y pass=12345 que el user y pass serian los 2 datos encriptados

Comment: bueno... la funcion aes_encrypt no funciona asi... mira la [documentacion](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/encryption-functions.html#function_aes-encrypt)... esta mal todo el query... y si quisieras pasar 2 parametros encriptados, deberias llamar a la funcion por cada parametro......

Comment: Buenas, ya cheque la documentación y ya pude encriptar un dato, pero ahora no me quiere desencriptar el date que hace unas líneas atrás la había encriptado
`mysql> insert into login (idu, user, pass) values('2', 'test02', aes_encrypt('test02', unhex(sha2('72003616',512))));
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.01 sec)`

`mysql> select aes_decrypt(pass,'72003616') from login;`

me aparece la table y dos datos en null